# How to access ionic serve -address

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

The ionic CLI gives the option to serve the app via

```
ionic serve -address=my.backend.server.com
```

How can I access the address given through this command in the project?

Answer (score 8):

If you need to host dev server on **all network interfaces** (i.e. --host=0.0.0.0), you can use

```
ionic serve --external
```

Then you will have the ability to access you application by navigating to any network interfaces IP (check `ipconfig` command)

```
http://192.168.1.68:8100/
...
```

If you need to host on **custom address**, please note that CUSTOM_ADDRESS_IP should be an available IP which is assigned to your actual device

```
ionic serve --address CUSTOM_ADDRESS_IP
```

Reference
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve#option-external

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve the application on your server and not on your local machine and reach the application through the public internet you could do the following:

```
ionic serve -address=0.0.0.0:8080
```

Then you should be able to reach the application on:

```
youripaddress:8080
```

if the dns zone entry file of your domain points to your server's ip adress you should also be able to reach your application through your domain:

```
yourdomain.com:8080
```

Also make sure that the firewall on your server accepts traffic to the port that the application is running on (in this example 8080)